# C# get bound of ssl server certificate

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, self-hosting, x509certificate2, netsh

I am running a self hosted web service. The communication is over https and I am using a self signed server certifivate. The Port is changeable. So on every application start I am looking for the certificate in the store and bind it to the specific port. This I am doing with netsh and delete/add.

Is there a way to find out if the command 'http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port}' was already executed by an application start before? So I do not have to delete and add it on every app-start.
My idea was to call 'http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port}' and look into the output. But this is not so nice.. 
So is there a C# method that is doing this?

```
public static bool ActivateCertificate(int port, X509Certificate2 certificate, string appId)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            bool certificateExists = false;

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            try
            {
            foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                if (cert.Thumbprint != null && cert.Thumbprint.Equals(certificate.Thumbprint, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    certificateExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!certificateExists)
            {
                store.Add(certificate);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Could not activate certificate!");
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo() {CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true};
        psi.FileName = "netsh";

        psi.Arguments = $"http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port}";
        Process procShow = Process.Start(psi);
        while (procShow != null && !procShow.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            str.Append(procShow.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
        Log.Warn(str.ToString);

        // delete IPV4.
        psi.Arguments = $"http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port}";
        Process procDel = Process.Start(psi);
        //exitCode = procDel.ExitCode;

        while (procDel != null && !procDel.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            str.Append(procDel.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
        Log.Warn(str.ToString);
        procDel?.WaitForExit(1000);
        // IPV4-Adresse hinzufügen.
        psi.Arguments = $"http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port} certhash={certificate.Thumbprint.ToLower()} appid={{{appId}}}";
        Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
        //exitCode = proc.ExitCode;

        while (proc != null && !proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            str.Append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
        /*
        // delete IPV6
        Log.Warn(str.ToString);
        proc?.WaitForExit(1000);
        psi.Arguments = $"http delete sslcert ipport=[::]:{port}";
        Process procDelV6 = Process.Start(psi);

        while (procDelV6 != null && !procDelV6.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            str.Append(procDelV6.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
        Log.Warn(str.ToString);
        procDelV6?.WaitForExit(1000);
        // IPV6-Adresse hinzufügen.
        psi.Arguments = $"http add sslcert ipport=[::]:{port} certhash={certificate.Thumbprint.ToLower()} appid={{{appId}}}";
        Process procV6 = Process.Start(psi);

        while (procV6 != null && !procV6.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            str.Append(procV6.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
        Log.Warn(str.ToString);
        procV6?.WaitForExit();
        */
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think the generally accepted way to do this is by calling netsh the way you are. You *could* look into [Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.binding(v=vs.90).aspx), but this depends on IIS being installed.

IMO it is perfectly valid to do `netsh http delete sslcert...` followed by `netsh http add sslcert...`. The `delete` will fail when the binding does not already exist, but that's okay.